# Merge PDF using PDFMergerUtility without losing Tags

Tags: java, accessibility, pdfbox

I am trying to merge a tagged PDF (Accessibility  enabled) file using `PDFMergerUtility` (*PDFBOX 2.0.10*) but the merged document does not retain the tags!

All PDFs are tagged.

Comment: instead of PDFMerger i have implemented using PdfCopy from Itext only

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in version 2.0.14. Versions up to 2.0.13 lose tags when merged from the command line or when `mergeDocuments()` is used. `appendDocument()` does not lose tags, but has other bugs that will also be fixed in 2.0.14. Until release it can be tested with a [snapshot](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.14-SNAPSHOT/) (number 120 or later).

Comment: thanks @Tilman Hausherr  we will try with this version and check

Comment: Some more bugs were fixed in 2.0.15, which can be tested here https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/pdfbox/2.0.15/

Comment: @TilmanHausherr can this be used to add htm mark up on the document

Comment: No, this can not.